# Functional Analysis: Finding finite functions over different norms

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces, signal-processing

$
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\Vert #1 \Vert}
\newcommand{\normc}{\Vert \cdot \Vert}
$For the three norms, $\normc_1,$ $\normc_2$, $\normc_{\infty}$ on the space of continuous real-valued signals defined on $(0, \infty)$, find a function for which the norm (it could be an improper integral) is finite only for that norm and not for the other two. Show that if $f$ is continuous and $\norm f_1$, and $\norm f_{\infty}$ are both finite then $\norm f_2$ is as well.

The hint in the exercise is that you can define your function piece-wise.

---

I know that the three norms look like this:
$$\norm f_1 = \sum_{t \in T}|f(t)|$$
$$\norm f_2 = \left(\sum_{t \in T}|f(t)|^2\right)^{1/2}$$
$$\norm f_{\infty} = \sup_{t \in T}|f(t)|$$
Where $T$ is the time domain (I believe in this exercise it would be the continuous real-valued signals, but I'm not 100% sure).

I'm not too sure what the functions should look like.

Comment: What's $T$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Should the last norm in the first paragraph be the sup norm?

Comment: @ArcticChar T is the time domain, I've made an edit to clarify

Comment: @G.Chiusole my mistake, I edited the question to fix the typo

Comment: @jejove2096 which functions have you tried? Were the norms finite or infinite?

Comment: Sorry what is the time domain? Indeed I am confused since you have real-valued signal defined on $(0,\infty)$, but then your norms seem to say that your signal is defined on a discrete set $T$.

Comment: Please don't self-delete your question with a high-quality answer again.  The loss of good content, especially the well-written answer, from the network has a negative impact on this site's SEO.

Answer (score 2):

$
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\Vert #1 \Vert}
\newcommand{\normc}{\Vert \cdot \Vert}
$For $p\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$, define

$$\norm{f}_p=\left(\int_0^\infty |f|^pdt\right)^{1/p}$$

and

$$\norm{f}_\infty=\sup_{(0,\infty)}|f|$$

(if they exist)

$p=1):$ Consider the function

$$f(t)=\max\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}-1,0\right)$$

Then

$$\norm{f}_1=\int_0^\infty |f|dt=\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}-1\right)dt=1$$

$$\norm{f}_2^2=\int_0^\infty |f|^2dt=\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}-1\right)^2dt=\int_0^1\left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{t}}+\frac{1}{t}+1\right)dt=\infty$$

$$\norm{f}_\infty=\infty$$

$p=2):$ Consider the function

$$f(t)=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{t^{1/4}} & t\leq 1 \\
      \frac{1}{t} & t\geq 1
   \end{cases}$$

Then

$$\norm{f}_1=\int_0^\infty |f|dt\geq \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t}dt=\infty$$

$$\norm{f}_2^2=\int_0^\infty |f|^2dt=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}dt+\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{t^2}dt=\frac{5}{3}$$

$$\norm{f}_\infty=\infty$$

$p=\infty):$ Consider the function

$$f(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t+1}}$$

Then

$$\norm{f}_1=\int_0^\infty |f|dt\geq \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{t+1}}dt=\infty$$

$$\norm{f}_2^2=\int_0^\infty |f|^2dt\geq \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t}dt=\infty$$

$$\norm{f}_\infty=1$$

For the second portion, assume that both $\norm{f}_1$ and $\norm{f}_\infty$ exist. From this, we know that $f(t)$ is bounded on $(0,\infty)$ (this bound is $M=\norm{f}_\infty$) and that

$$\norm{f}_1=\int_0^\infty |f|dt<\infty$$

This implies that

$$\frac{|f|^2}{M^2}=\left(\frac{|f|}{M}\right)^2<\frac{|f|}{M}$$

(since $\frac{|f|}{M}\leq 1$). Therefore

$$\norm{f}_2^2=\int_0^\infty |f|^2dt=M^2\int_0^\infty \frac{|f|^2}{M^2}dt<M^2\int_0^\infty \frac{|f|}{M}dt=M\norm{f}_1<\infty$$

We conclude $\norm{f}_2$ is also finite.